# How to change the height of the parent div of a plotly_app iframe in python/django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, plotly

I am trying to change the height of the parent div of an iframe but cannot find out how to.
Here is an image of how the html structure is when I use my Google browser's inspect tool (I did not write this html, it is created by plotly):

[image]

The highlighted div contains the height that I am trying to change. Currently, the height is set to 0.
(padding-bottom is set to 10% since the ratio in the html is set to 0.1 since I have been testing everything I can think of but I have the ratio set to .35

The following shows how I call the plotly_app in the html:

[image]

Here is how the views.py has the scatter_app layout:

[image]

I have attempted to add 'height': '90%' the styles of the 'html.Div' and the 'dcc.Graph' but these change the height of the html inside of the iFrame.
Therefore, nothing changes since I need to change the height of the parent div.

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `{% plotly_app name='scatter_app_name' %}` to be inside a div and added a CSS rule to overflow the 0 height of the original div that encpasulates the iframe:

```
{% load plotly_dash %}
<div id="container_iframe">
    {% plotly_app name='scatter_app_name' %}
</div>

<style>
    #container_iframe div{
        height: 100%!important  ;
    }
</style>
```

Worked for me on Firefox and Chrome.